# Dynamic Title in angularjs - using ng-attr-title

Tags: angularjs

How can i get a dynamic title in angularJS.I know to use `ng-attr-title` as given below

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-attr-title="{{title}}">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

and the controller is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function ctrl($scope){
$scope.title = "I 'm a tooltip!";    
}
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hj53npf3/) and its working.  What i am trying is to have two different titles one while enabled and another while disabled so i want to decide the variable that goes in to `ng-attr-title` at runtime as given below.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-attr-title="{{message}}">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

and the controller is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function ctrl($scope){
$scope.Enabledtitle = "U can click me";
$scope.Disabledtitle = "U cannot click me";
 $scope.message="Enabledtitle";    
}
```

So when i hover i should get the tooltip saying  "U can click me". SO that i get the flexibility to switch between the tooltip messages just by updating the scope variable `message`

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oetd3bvy/1/) where i tried the dynamic title and am getting "Enabledtitle" as tooltip instead of "U can click me".

How can i tell angular to parse `{{Enabledtitle}}` and gimme its value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property with the variable name. So the title attribute becomes `ng-attr-title="{{this[message]}}`:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.Enabledtitle = "U can click me";
    $scope.Disabledtitle = "U cannot click me";
    $scope.message = "Enabledtitle";
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-attr-title="{{this[message]}}">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

In your case, `this` points to current scope object `$scope` and you are reading it's property by dynamic key `message`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oetd3bvy/2/

Answer (score 8):

In the controller:

```
$scope.getMessage() {
    return isEnabled ? "You can click me" : "You can't click me";
}
```

in the view:

```
<div title="{{ getMessage() }}">...</div>
```

Or, every time the code changes the value of the `isEnabled` flag, also change the message.

Comment: Can we also pass a variable to ``getMessage()``, for example, if the ``div`` is defined within an ``ng-repeat`` element?

Comment: @user1438038 yes, you can.

Answer (score 2):

do

```
$scope.message=$scope.Enabledtitle;
```

instead of

```
$scope.message="Enabledtitle";
```